# If two functions' limit when multiplied is 0, do either of those function's limits need be 0?

Tags: real-analysis

So, there are two variants of this question and I think I have the right answer, but I want to confirm.

(Q1) If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions such that $\lim_{x\to p} (fg)(x) = 0$, then either $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to p} g(x) = 0$.

My answer: No since we can define $f(x) = 0$, if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x) = 3$, if $x> 0$ and $g(x) = 3$, if $x \leq 0$ and $g(x) = 0$, if $x > 0$. In this case, at $p=0$, neither limits exist for f or g, but $f \cdot g = 0$, so after we take the limit on both sides, we get $\lim_{x \to 0} (fg)(x)  = 0$.

(Q2) If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are *continuous* functions such that $\lim_{x\to p} (fg)(x) = 0$, then either $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to p} g(x) = 0$.

My answer: Yes! This is because $\lim_{x \to p} fg(x) = 0 \implies \left(\lim_{x\to p} f(x)\right) \left(\lim_{x\to p} g(x)\right) = 0$ (because they are continuous). The only way this can happen is if either of the two limits of f or g are 0.

Is that correct?

Comment: I fixed it for you but in the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset. You are not a new user so this is more-or-less an expectation of the community.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Ah, yes, I apologize, it's been a while since I used this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proofs look good. You should note in the continuous case that $\lim_{x \to p} f(x), \lim_{x \to p} g(x)$ both exist (which is true by continuity), so you can apply the multiplicativity of limits.

As Marko Karbevski notes, this doesn't work with $p= \infty$ (which I didn't take to be part of the scope of your question, but is an important note). For this you need the existence of the limits at infinity, which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: The case at p=$\infty$ has been taken care of in the comments of that answer

Comment: Also, the question asks for a specific point p, I don't think we can use infinity in that case

Comment: $p$ is not in the domain of the function. You would need the function to extend to a continuous function on the extended reals, but as you say this is not part of the question, so let's not worry about it.

Comment: If you're question has been resolved, please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark.

Comment: Not yet, I want to resolve this infinity business. P.S. Ok I marked it, but I still wanna know the answer to the infinity stuff

Comment: Please ask another question. We like to have a 1 question per post if possible.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it only dealt with the case $p = \infty$. In any case, it is possible to construct a counter-example in that given scenario. Here is an outline of an idea: Let $0 \le f,g \le 1$ be two real functions. Note that if $f$ is decreasing and $g$ is increasing on a finite nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=g(b) =1$ and $f(b)=g(a)=0$ then $f\times g \le f(t) = g(t)$  where $t \in [a,b]$ is the point for which $f(t) = g(t)$. Now make sure that on consecutive intervals $[n^2, (n+1)^2] $, $f(t_n)$  gets smaller and $f, 1-g$ are increasing if n is odd and decreasing otherwise